# Perform operation before dequeue in C#

Tags: c#, queue

There are several download requests which i want to serve one by one and for this reason i am using Queue. Here is the list, which is populating from different scripts at different times

```
 public Queue<WebDownloader> webDownloaderQ;
```

A public method allow to different scripts/resource to populate the queue dynamically at different times:

```
 public void EnqueABDownloading(WebDownloader abToDownload)
    {
        singleAbLoader.Enqueue(abToDownload);
    }
```

The download starts quickly as it found even a single que object, (Remember during this time queue can be incremented),

```
     public void StartDownloading()
        {
            //while (singleAbLoader.Count > 0)
            //{
            //    singleAbLoader.

            //}

            for (int i = 0; i < singleAbLoader.Count; i++)
            {
                singleAbLoader[i].//this is not supporting unable to call my method
//I want to call one of the function (startdowloaind) of WebDownloader before the deque 
            }
        }
```

I tried to write above function for downloading but the problem is, i dont know how to do this. I tried to used index with the object it saying cannot apply indexing with to an expression of type Queue.

**EDIT:**

**Remember**: I want to call one of the function (`StartDowloaind`) of `WebDownloader` before the Dequeue the object.

I want to first enqueue the request, the reason is that every request will take sometime to download. Therefore,

1. first enqueue the download request
2. then, check download loop is running or not if not then, initiate
   the loop
3. As specific download complete dequeue the request.

Comment: Use `foreach` instead. But who dont you just start the download when you enqueue it?

Comment: Can you be more specific

Comment: Do this instead `singleAbLoader.ElementAt(i)`, Queue<T> doesnt provide an indexer because it implements `IEnumerable<T>` and `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Dont use `ElementAt` as it needs to iterate the collection every time you call it.

Comment: @Magnus true that it will be a `O(n)` access, but still its recommended to use the `foreach` loop instead.

Comment: More information added in the question please check.

Comment: @Magnus I want to first enqueue, the reason is that every request will take sometime to download. therefore, first enque, then, check loop is running or not if not then, initiate the loop.

Comment: I have added more information, including the steps. Please check.

Comment: I'd suggest what you want is two queues (or more likely `BlockingCollection`s). `NeedToDownloadQueue` and `FinishedDownloadingQueue`. Both can be `BlockingCollection`. Add items to the first queue. Have a dedicated thread that reads from the queue, one by one, and initiates downloads. Once they are done, add entries to the second queue.

Comment: I still don't understand why you cant enqueue it and start the download at the same time... And hook up the event to handle the dequeue when the download is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use Dequeue Method to pop up the item like the following

```
while (singleAbLoader.Count>0)
(
WebDownloader method= singleAbLoader.Dequeue();
 method.StartDowloaind();

}
```

by this way even if the queue is incremented it will continue to use pop up and without the need for the index .

I also suggest to use `ConcurrentQueue` if the queue will be used by multiple threads

Comment: i want to call one of the function (startdowloaind) of WebDownloader before the deque

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan i think we could make a dequeue then call the start download function and if any error happend we enqueue again , what do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` to loop through your queue. `foreach` does not Dequeue

```
 public void StartDownloading()
 {
        foreach(WebDownloader wd in singleAbLoader)
        {
             wd.Start();
        }
 }
```

Considering your comment:

As downloads may not complete in the order they start, so use a `List` instead of Queue.

Your class `WebDownloader` obviously has something like `DownloadCompleted` event, you can remove it from the list in there. or if you need it, just then add it to a queue of completed downloads.

Comment: I am not only want to start the loading but also want to dequeue, if specific download complete.